# /: is a directory issue in bash

Tags: bash, directory

I'm quite new to bash scripting and have been going reasonably well but have run into an issue.

I am trying to create a script that uses a forward slash (/), however, I keep getting the error message `/: is a directory.`

So basically what I need is to pass the command `test/(hello)` to a program in the terminal. So I have added backslashes to make it work: `test\/\(hello\)`, however, I get this error. What is wrong here?

Comment: *where* does the script use the forward slash? It sounds like you *are* successfully passing the *argument* to the command/script, but that there is an error in the script. Can you give us a more detailed example? Also, doesn't it mention a line number or something?

Answer (score 5):

This should only happen if you are not passing a command before the argument. You need to invoke commands like so:

```
command [args ...]
```

If you invoke it like this, it will work.

```
$ echo test/\(hello\)
test/(hello)
```

For the record, it's generally much easier (and much more readable) to quote arguments instead of escaping all metacharacters. You can do this using `"` and `'` (there's good information about this [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)).

Comment: Upvoted.  The shell will interpreted text separated only by slashes as directories, not commands/arguments.  The forward slash can be used in arguments of, for example, Perl scripts (requires configuring `Getopt::Long` or rolling your own), but still requires the space between the command and arguments -- again, this is a shell requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass the exact string `test/(hello)` to a program, put it between single quotes:

```
someprogram 'test/(hello)'
```

Every character is interpreted literally between single quotes, except the single quote character itself. If you need a single quote character in the string, pass it as `'\''` (end literal string, quote next character, single quote interpreted literally, start literal string).

```
echo 'Lasciate ogne speranza, voi ch'\''entrate'
```

This is unrelated to the error message you show here. `/: is a directory` means that you tried to execute `/` as a program. There is presumably a place where you tried to write the full path to a program but left an extra space, as in

```
/ path/to/program
```

There may be other punctuation characters making this less obvious, or control characters in that message. To facilitate debugging, put `set -x` on the second line of the script, just after the initial `#!` line, so that the shell will print a trace of every line it executes.